# Symfony2 + SonataPageBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I try to install SonataPageBundle on Symfony2, but I get an error during the bundle configuration...

I followed the Official Documentation for install the bundle and at the 3.3 step when I run the following command:

```
php app/console sonata:page:create-snapshots -site=all
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher' not found in /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2631

Have you any idea about my problem?

Comment: which version of SF2 and which version of Sonata Page do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace all the

`Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher`

In the project to

`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher`

I just did this and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You may use Symfony 2.0, and missing

```
Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher
```

You can download package symfony 2.1 or master in https://github.com/symfony/symfony

Copy file  ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php in `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher` folder in to your Symfony 2.0 (`vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher`)

I did it, worked fine!